# ShapefileFeatureTable cannot be converted to FeatureTable with Android?

Tags: android

I'm creating an Android application to display shapefiles. I'm using this code that I found on the Internet:

```
try {
        ShapefileFeatureTable shapefileFeatureTable = new ShapefileFeatureTable("file:///mnt/sdcard/ShapeFile/LVA_water_lines_dcw.shp");
        FeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(shapefileFeatureTable);
        featureLayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(new SimpleFillSymbol(
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright),
                SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE.SOLID)));
        map.addLayer(featureLayer);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, R.string.shapefile_not_found, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

But it gives me the error:

```
ShapefileFeatureTable cannot be converted to FeatureTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a wrong import.

```
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.layers.FeatureLayer;
```

instead of

```
import com.esri.android.map.FeatureLayer;
```